Cannot build project inside VSC for a ESP32 devKit with the ESP-IDF express installed
I'm stuck after following a very clear tutorial on the use of ESP-IDF on VSC. I'm using a basic ESP32 devkit and I want to run the blink project demo code. I'm using VSC version 1.90.0 and ESP-IDF version 5.0.6. I followed this tutorial for the IDF installation: text
I did the exact same thing as him, except for the name of the folders.
The problem is that when I created my project from the blink example, when I click on ESP-IDF : Build your project, I end up with an infinite loop that simply displays :
`

Executing task: ninja

The specified path cannot be found.
C:\randompath\hello_world\build>`
I'm not sure what to do, I've looked in the user documentation for similar problems but nothing.
I used to have a configuration for ESP8266 with MinGW but I deleted everything, including the access paths. I was working with eclipse 2023.
I've reinstalled the extension, ESP-IDF and the project but nothing changes. I've tried to look at my access paths, to look in json without really knowing what to look for.
